# JHipster - How to test angularJS client side when client has java servlet dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jhipster

What's the approach for performing client side testing in JHipster (in fact in any AngularJS app), when you have dependencies on java configuration components such as Spring configuration in application context, as well as servlet filters.

For example, we are using a ping federate jar installed in the Tomcat lib folder, combined with a  setting in context.xml which we rely on for populating the java security principal via single sign on.

I have a basic grasp on doing (1) pure backend java testing using unity tests via Maven and (2) how I would create tests for a pure HTML/JS solution on the front end. But when you are dependent on servlet front end components when doing java development - what's the general approach?  Running a GRUNT server isn't good enough...it has to be a servlet container like Tomcat.

Thanks

i

Comment: I dont know much about JHipster but on their website they mentioned Karma for front end testing.So, you must go for karma for angular Javascript testing.
"http://jhipster.github.io/presentation/#/3/4"

Comment: Hi, thats my issue - I have to be serving this out of apache tomcat as a servlet container.  Not out of a non servlet container like a grunt server.

Comment: I'm afraid the question isn't clear. How do you say *"pure HTML/JS solution on the frontend"* then say that it's also *"dependant on servlet front-end components"*?

Comment: Hi, sorry what I meant was I am not using JSP or JSF for the front end, I am using HTML and javascript (angularJS).  However, there are elements of the application which are dependent on Tomcat to deal with single sign on using jar files in the Tomcat lib folder, and a <Valve> statement in the web.xml file to cause single sign on to work.  So I can't just fire it up outside of a servlet container, as it is dependent on web.xml and the tomcat environment.